# Woher kommt der Ausdruck "sich zusammenreißen"

Tags: etymology, phrase

ich bin heute mal wieder über das Verb

> "sich zusammenreißen"

im Sinne von

> "Jetzt reiß' dich mal zusammen"

gestolpert. Von der reinen Bedeutung her ist das Wort unlogisch, da reißen immer eine "Auseinander-bewegung" impliziert.

Wie ist dieser Begriff aber entstanden und wie konnte er sich so stark etablieren (zumindest in Bayern)

Comment: Interessant wäre auch die Frage nach "sich am Riemen reißen" ... verwandte Ausdrücke!?

Comment: Hab zwischenzeitlich einen Beitrag gefunden, der auf einen Zusammenhang von "sich zusammenreißen" mit "die Hacken zusammenreißen" -also strammstehen- hinaus will. Weiß nicht, was ich davon halten soll, wollte es nur erwähnen, falls Du dem nachgehen möchtest.

Comment: Hast du nen link dazu ?

Comment: Wollte das eigentlich in das Kommentar reineditieren, aber hab wohl zu lange gewartet ... http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/wie-soll-man-sich-zusammenreissen-das-geht-doch-im-woertlichen-sinne-gar-nicht-woher-kommt-dieser-ausdruck -> erste Antwort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das sind jetzt meine eigenen Gedanken zu dem Thema, habe da keine Belege für, aber:

1. Es gibt ja den Begriff "sich zusammennehmen".
2. Für mich stellt "sich zusammenreißen" eine Steigerung von "sich zusammennehmen" dar.
3. Es gibt nicht nur reißen in der Form der "Auseinanderbewegung", man kann ja auch "Sachen an sich reißen", was die Steigerung von "an sich nehmen" ist.

Nur so ein Gedankengang, ich hoffe man kann mir folgen.

Comment: Das ist sogar ein sehr guter Gedanke, auf den bin ich so noch nicht gekommen. Problem ist nur, dass sich zusammennehmen die selbe Unlogik bedient. Etwas zusammennehmen hat eine gewisse Logik, aber "sich zusammennehmen" finde ich schon wieder schwierig

Comment: Naja, "sich zusammennehmen" verfolgt die gleiche Logik (auch wenn es nicht die gleiche Bedeutung hat), wie "sich sammeln" oder "sich konzentrieren", oder? Also die wirren Teile des Selbst zum Zentrum zu holen um (jetzt im Fall sammeln/konzentrieren) eine fundierte Entscheidung zu treffen ...

Comment: hm... also dass "sich zusammenreißen" sozusagen als Steigerung bedeutet, die "wirren Teile des Selbst" mit "Gewalt" zum Zentrum zu holen ?

Comment: Ja, ich drifte da ein bisschen ab. Was ich sagen möchte ist im Prinzip, in einer Situation, in der man jemandem sagt, er soll "sich zusammenreißen" kann es ja sein das er "ganz aufgelöst" oder "in Scherben" ist ... der Aufruf ist, sich (in der Steigerung mit Gewalt) aufzuraffen / zusammenzusetzen ...

Comment: Wie gesagt, vielleicht ist es nur Spinnerei ...

Comment: klingt aber gar nicht so verkehrt :) Aber das ist eh alles nur spekulation, bis jemand mit einer Antwort auf Grundlage von Quellen und sonstigen Beweisen ankommt :)

Comment: Ja, da bin ich auch gespannt ... werde die Frage beobachten :)

Answer (score 6):

Im Grimmschen Wörterbuch [Zusammenreiszen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=zusammenbeiszen) finden sich Belege, die etwa zum selben Ergebnis führen: ein "kräftiger ausdruck für sich zusammennehmen s. den bel. bei zusammenbeiszen.", dort wird es zurück geführt auf das Zähne [Zusammenbeiszen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=zusammenreiszen). Man nehme das der Gesundheit zuliebe also lieber nicht wörtlich, oder mache mindestens keine Gewohnheit daraus.

Schön finde ich den Verweis auf die Jägersprache, "die hunde haben das wild zusammengerissen": Wir sammeln unsere wilden Regungen an einer Stelle, zu einem Zweck, wenn wir uns selbst zusammenreissen.

Comment: Dasselbe Bild gibt es übrigens auch im Englischen, to pull oneself together. Wer hat da von wem etwas übernommen?

Answer (score 1):

Könnte "reißen" die ruckartige Bewegung an sich meinen? Unabhängig der Richtung in die gerissen wird? Ich hatte den Begriff zunächst auch als Synonym zu "etwas mit Gewalt trennen" aufgefasst, doch damit lag ich, glaube ich, falsch.
Grüße